# merge two arrays of strings to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapreduce

I have two arrays that look like this:

```
const players = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"]
const games = ["gid1", "gid2"]
```

I need to return an array that looks like this:

```
const newArray = [
  {playerId: "id1", gameId: "gid1"}, {playerId: "id1", gameId: "gid2"},
  {playerId: "id2", gameId: "gid1"}, {playerId: "id2", gameId: "gid2"},
  {playerId: "id3", gameId: "gid1"}, {playerId: "id3", gameId: "gid2"},
  {playerId: "id4", gameId: "gid1"}, {playerId: "id4", gameId: "gid2"}
]
```

What's the best way to achieve this? I have been trying a combination of map and reduce, but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @charlietfl: Looks like a cartesian product. But would be good if it said.

Comment: *"I have been trying a combination of map and reduce, but can't seem to figure it out."* Show us that. Separately: Why reach for something complicated when nested loops will do the job nicely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Array.reduce()` and `Array.forEach()` functions:

```js
const players = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"]
const games = ["gid1", "gid2"]

const result = players.reduce((r, p_id) => {
    games.forEach((g_id) => r.push({playerId: p_id, gameId: g_id}));
    return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to create cartesian array. You can perform it like this;

```
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    for (var l = 0; l < games.length; l++) {
        var merged = {playerId: players[i], gameId: games[l]};
        newArray.push(merged);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using es6 for...of

```
const players = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4']
const games = ['gid1', 'gid2']
let newArray = []

for (let game of games) {
   for (let player of players) {
       newArray.push({playerId: player, gameId: game})
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different take on the functional approach which breaks down the code into smaller parts:

```js
const players = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"]
const games = ["gid1", "gid2"];

const flatten = arrs => [].concat(...arrs);
const getGame = (id, gid) => ({ playerId: id, gameId: gid });
const getGames = games => id => games.map(gid => getGame(id, gid));
const output = flatten(players.map(getGames(games)));

console.log(output)
```